# How may I move the pre-installed applications (such as Chess) into a sub-folder?

Tags: macos, applications, high-sierra

The Applications folder is way too crowded to be useful. It could be nice if I could just get the pre-installed applications that I don't use swept into a sub-folder under the Applications, named as something like "Unused Built-ins".

Then again, I cannot move any of them, nor delete them. It just won't allow me to. Am I stuck with all those mess, like an advertisement that I cannot dismiss? I just want my space, inside that Applications folder of mine, or at least I thought it was mine...

How may I move, say the `Applications/Chess.app/` to `Applications/Unused/Chess.app/` with the purpose of having less items in the Applications folder? Alternative solutions are welcome as comments.

Comment: If you really want to move a protected app from /Applications to another location **it can be done!** Boot to Recovery HD and temporarily disable System Integrity Protection and reboot to normal mode. Then in Terminal use, e.g. `sudo mv /Applications/Chess.app /Applications/Unsed/` (Note the destination directory must already exist.) When finished moving apps then enable SIP. The primary drawback is when you update the OS moved protected app may/will be replaced and need to be moved again. BTW If you want to delete it the ACL on it has to be removed. **But either are doable!**

Answer (score 1):

You can't. There are hacks that allow you to do this but really you are spending a lot of time and effort and compromising the stability and security of the Mac so your /Applications folder can be neat/tidy.

May I suggest you create a folder in which you place aliases of all applications that you want and need and use that in place of the /Applications folder and just stay out of that folder?

Comment: I had done this yesterday right after I have posted this question. I don't consider this as a good solution, though, because now I have to put an alias to every application I will be installing in the future.

Comment: Additionally, now I have a folder filled with alias/symlink icons on their bottom right corners as my "Useful Applications". I looked up ways to remove the alias/symlink icon overlay: It seems that this also cannot be done with the integrity protection intact...